# Ajax append more data from database when user scrolls laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Ok, so the trigger for the autoload method is already working:

```
window.onscroll = function(evt){
    autoload();
};
```

autoload() function:

```
function autoload(){
    $.ajax({
        //What do i need to do here to get data from 
        //the URL and append it to #contentContainer?
      })
}
```

The route is already done, feel free to adjust it to GET if you like:

```
Route::post('/loadMore', 'HomeController@loadMore');
```

loadMore function:

```
return View::make('partials.home');
```

If partials.home is a div in which css is applied, and some blade templating, but in the end. it returns a div which i need to append to #contentContainer.

Have any questions? I would be happy to answer them!

Answer (score 0):

You can load your content and add it your container like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: {{ URL::to('/loadMore') }},
  data: {key1:value1, key2: value2}, // if you need to send some data to your function
  success: function(data){
    $('#contentContainer').append(data);
  }
});
```

Remarque: I am supposing that you are writing your javascript inside a `.blade.php` file so that you can use `{{ URL::to('/loadMore') }}` to generate the URL to your route

Comment: Thanks for the help! but unfortunately, it doesn't work.. The "{{}}" doesn't work.. in javascript you can't use blade templating.. Or at least it gives an error on that part

Comment: If you are writing in a seperate js file. You can do `url: '/loadMore',` simply, it should work fine.

Comment: Ok cool, so now i get into the successfunction (proven by an alert), but the div doesn't get appended.. what does that mean?

Comment: Try to `console.log(data)` to know what you get exactly

Comment: Nothing, data is empty, in the console i see main.js line 44 (which is the line of the console.log(data). but then nothing is in there. So data is empty for some reason?

Comment: I got it! look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the view:

My view began with:

```
@section('content')
```

javascript appearantly can't deal with that